# How to make the line red and blue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/1xcdLtv8/), which is working fine for pathing:

[image]

But i need begin RED and the end line BLUE, i tried by putting context.strokeStyle = 'blue'; but it failed.

Do you know how you can do that?

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var shape = new Path2D();

function init(){
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'red';


// RED RED RED
shape.moveTo(100,20);
shape.lineTo(200, 160);
shape.quadraticCurveTo(0, 200, 250, 120);
shape.bezierCurveTo(290, -40, 300, 200, 400, 150);


// BLUE BLUE
//---- make this BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE not RED RED RED
//---- make this BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE not RED RED RED
// line 2 
//---- make this BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE not RED RED RED
//---- make this BLUE BLUE BLUE BLUE not RED RED RED
shape.lineTo(500, 90);

draw();
}    

var pos = 0;
var l = 760;
function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.setLineDash([pos, l-pos]);
    context.stroke(shape);
    pos = pos+3;
    if(pos >= l){
        blink();
        return;
        }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};
var i = 0;
function blink(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if((++i % 30) > 15){
        context.stroke(shape);
        }

    requestAnimationFrame(blink);
    };
init();
```

Comment: check my answer..

Comment: look at my answer it will give you the exact effect you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient style stroke

```
var gradient=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,170,0);
gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");

// Fill with gradient
context.strokeStyle=gradient;
context.lineWidth=5;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_strokestyle.asp

Comment: bro i don't think this is an recommended process! correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @ASK, you're wrong. What could not be recommended would be to create too much different gradients in an animation loop, but here you can create it only once at the init stage and it's just fine to use it.

Comment: The major problem with this trick is that the linear gradient is like a full rectangle area covering the context. This means that it doesn't actually follow the path : https://jsfiddle.net/1xcdLtv8/2/ To circumvent this, you'll have to draw every point on the path independently : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5281/navigating-along-a-path#t=201612081418450209939

Comment: yep exactly.... but the OP didn't ask for that he wanted it to follow his path according to the question...

Answer (score 1):

Use `strokeStyle` property of `canvas` API to achieve the desired color. Here's an example:

```
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle="#0000FF"; //  Change color to blue
ctx.strokeRect(20,20,150,100);
```

Draws a blue rectangle.

Since you are using `Path2D` you'll have to use different `path` to draw with different `colors`.

**Here is an example to achieve it with animation.**

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid;">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Array of shapes which has different colors
var shapes = [ new Path2D(),   // RED shape
               new Path2D()    // BLUE shape
];

// Parallel Array to store color for each shape
var colors = [
                "#ff0000", // RED
                "#0000ff"  // BLUE
];

// Parallel Array to store length of each shape
var length_of_shapes =[
    644,        // Approx Length of RED shape
    116         // Length of Blue shape
];

var pos=0;      // Position 

var l=0;        // Total length

function init(){
    context.lineWidth = 1;

    // RED Shape
    shapes[0].moveTo(100,20);
    shapes[0].lineTo(200, 160);
    shapes[0].quadraticCurveTo(0, 200, 250, 120);
    shapes[0].bezierCurveTo(290, -40, 300, 200, 400, 150);

    // BLUE Shape
    shapes[1].moveTo(400, 150);
    shapes[1].lineTo(500, 90);

    calcTotalLength();
    draw();
}    


// Function to calculate total length
function calcTotalLength(){
    for (var i = 0; i < length_of_shapes.length; i++) {
        l+=length_of_shapes[i];
    };
}


// Function to draw a shape at index i
function drawShape(i){
    context.strokeStyle = colors[i];
    context.stroke(shapes[i]);
}


function draw() {
    var length_of_prev_shapes=0;

    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);     // Clear the canavas

    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        if(pos < (length_of_prev_shapes + length_of_shapes[i])){        // If the current shape is still drawing

            // Is this the first shape then position is pos else it is the remainder of pos divided by length_of_prev_shapes
            var tmpPos=(length_of_prev_shapes !== 0) ? (pos % length_of_prev_shapes) : pos; 

            context.setLineDash([ tmpPos, (length_of_shapes[i] - tmpPos) ]);        // Add drawing effect

            drawShape(i);       // Draw Shape at i

            // If the current shape is still drawing no point in looping through all other shapes so break
            break;      
        }else{                          
            context.setLineDash([0]);   // Remove the drawing effect

            // Add the length of the current shape to the length of all other drawn shapes
            length_of_prev_shapes += length_of_shapes[i];   

            drawShape(i);       // Draw Shape at i
        }
    };

    pos+=3;     // Increase position by 3

    // If all the points are drawn i.e the position is greater than length
    if(pos >= l){   
        blink();    // Blink
        return;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

var i = 0;
function blink(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if((++i % 30) > 15){
        for(var j=0;j < shapes.length;j++){
            drawShape(j);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(blink);
}
init();
</script>
```

**Advantages of using this method**

1. It's easy to use.
2. It's easy to understand as it's documented well.
3. It will give the exact effect the question is asking for.

**Drawback of this method**

1. You will first have to find the `length` of all the `shape` which has not been covered here.
2. Finding the length of curves can be a little bit intimidating.
3. The `speed` of the `animation` depends upon the `accuracy` of the `length` of `curves` which will allow the `draw` function to be called less often.
4. To change the `color` of the part of the `shape` you'll have to define a different `shape`.

[More details here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors)

[An Example](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/an-example-of-html5-canvas-path2d-objects.html) to draw with `Path2D`

Comment: How are you gonna mix it with setLineDash ?

Comment: Thank you, wish i could answer both.

Comment: Well it's still kinda fixed isn't it ? Just had a quick look at it, but if you want to change the color threshold position, you also have to rewrite the whole paths declarations don't you ? https://jsfiddle.net/70ko8y24/

Comment: @Kaiido yep.. but look on the bright side of it you will know exactly what color your shape will be but if you were using gradient it would be impossible to do so...